# What does "tol" mean in a gear box?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

In [this NASA document](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20000036534.pdf), it is mentioned on page 221 (239 of the pdf) that a "23 tol gear box" was used. What does that mean?

A google search for "23 tol gear box" (with quotes) comes up completely empty, and "tol gear box" shows only irrelevant results. A search for just tol doesn't come up with any convincing results either. I can't rule out that it is a typo of some sort.

From the context I presume it to mean that the gearbox output runs 23 times as fast as the powered side, but I have to be certain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, I get it. The typo is a missing space. It's supposed to mean "23 to 1".

Comment: I'd leave it. Anyone else searching for the same thing now has an answer. You just made the internet that much more useful.

Comment: I'd say it's your option whether to delete or not. We do not have the same typo policy that Stack Overflow does and your problem statement is well-formed. I'm not sure how likely someone else is to find this useful, though.

Comment: I agree with both of you. I guess I'll leave it for now. The internet is a large place, and someone someday may have the same problem in a badly scanned document.

Comment: @Samuel Since I am getting upvotes almost a year after posting, I guess I am not the only one sifting through old NASA documents. I have a feeling I know who it may be. Oi a todos! :)